# Core Location does't update the significant location changes

Tags: ios, core-location

In my app(Deployment Target 5.1), i am using CoreLocation to setup a reminder feature, it will basically search the nearby items(have location attached) as device update its current location.

This feature is not working very stable at this stage, sometimes it just doesn't works at all regardless of whether device is in active, suspended and terminated states. i realized that the delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` didn't get call.

Is there anybody can point me a direction to make this thing work properly?

Here is my setup for the CLLocationManager

```
sharedLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
[ESLocationManager defaultManager].delegate = someDelegateClassInstance;
[[ESLocationManager defaultManager] setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
[[ESLocationManager defaultManager] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

And the implementation of the delegate callback

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 20.0) {
        // If the event is recent,find nearby items.
        NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
              newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
              newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

        //reload nearby list
        NSArray *nearbyItems = [self nearbyItemsForLocation:newLocation];
        if (nearbyItems && nearbyItems.count ) {
            UIApplicationState appState = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
            if (appState != UIApplicationStateActive) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:[self localNotificationForItems:nearbyItems]];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? How are you testing it? Also note that the significant location change service does not use the desired accuracy property. You will only get new locations when the device connects to a different cell tower.

Comment: I tested it on the simulator with gpx files, it works fine on iPhone 6.1, but poor on iPhone 5.1, by playing around with location, i can see the list was updated and i was able to receive the notifications while device was inactive or terminated. However when i was testing it on the actual device, it was not working at all. i suspect the problem is due to the location update is very much depends on the nearby cell tower on the device. -_-

Answer (score -1):

Similar reason to this forum with region monitoring

https://devforums.apple.com/message/251046#251046

Hope this helps